# meaning of ICC in rergression

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, stat

I'm stuck on this question and can not find a logical explanation.
I'm given the following regression output -

[image]

The question is this - a one-way analysis model of variance was mistakenly adapted to explain the variable “level of violence” using the random factor “grade” The grade factor in this study is a constant factor. The partial results in the output are based on a balanced experiment.

Does it make sense in this case to calculate the ICC? Is it at all possible to calculate it manually from this output data only?
I know that the ICC describes the relationship between the observations within the groups. So I thought maybe to describe the connection within the classes, and between the different classes. But how can the ICC be reached by manual calculation from the data in the output?

Comment: There is a way from this output to calculate ICC by manual calculation from the data in the output? I need the DF of class for it, no?

Comment: any explain please?

Comment: if someone know it, please i'd like to read an explain

Comment: any explain please?

Comment: You posted this in the wrong place. Should have been sent to stats.stackexchange.com